# link and image helper error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i try to use lightbox , i was follow all steps  in this [link](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) but the problem in the code

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
<img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="" />
</a>
```

i put images folder in the webroot

```
C:\wamp\www\tet\app\webroot\img\images
```

instead of the above code i use

```
$thumb = $this->Html->image('images/thumb-1.jpg');
$full = $this->Html->image('/images/image-1.jpg', array('rel' => 'lightbox'));
echo $this->Html->link($thumb,$full, array('escape' => false));
```

but i still see this error

```
Missing Method in ImagesController

Error: The action <img src=" is not defined in controller ImagesController

Error: Create ImagesController::<img src="() in file: app\controllers\images_controller.php.

<?php
class ImagesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Images';


    function <img src="() {

    }

}
?>
```

any help please

Answer (score 0):

because you are doing it wrong. It should be like

```
   $this->Html->image('images/thumb-1.jpg', array('url' => 'images/image-1.jpg'));
```

Comment: no your code is not true ,, because i but the images folder like this C:\wamp\www\tet\app\webroot\img\images

Comment: in that case remove the leading slash. I have updated the code.

Comment: no it is not work .. when i click on the image the link prodused like this http://localhost/tet/images/images/image-1.jpg...and still see this error Missing Method in ImagesController

Error: The action images is not defined in controller ImagesController

Error: Create ImagesController::images() in file: app\controllers\images_controller.php.

<?php
class ImagesController extends AppController {

 var $name = 'Images';


 function images() {

 }

}
?>